# Is it possible to refactor this to use generics?

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

Using LINQ to Entities, I have the following code:

```
public Foo GetFooByID(int id)
{
 return _db.Foo.First(m => m.ID == id);
}

public Bar GetBarByID(int id)
{
 return _db.Bar.First(m => m.ID == id);
}
```

Is there a way to refactor this using generics?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the LINQ to SQL [DataContext.GetTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.gettable.aspx) method:

```
public T GetById<T>(int id)
{
  return _db.GetTable<T>().First(m => m.ID = id);
}
```

Then you would call it like so:

```
GetById<Foo>(10);
GetById<Bar>(10);
```

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was hoping for, except that LINQ to Entities doesn't use DataContext.

Comment: you could use Type.GetProperties on your _db to see if it has any properties of type T.

Comment: For some reason, Type.GetType("myEDMX") returns null.

Comment: @chris if you use the fully qualified name you get a type instead of null. (If you're unsure about the fully qualified name write this in watch/immediate window: typeof(yourtype).AssemblyQualifiedName (you might be able to use FullName too)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to abstract access to the property `Foo` and `Bar` on `_db` first. Then the generic part becomes pretty straight forward.

```
public T GetByID<T>(int id) 
{
 return _db.GetCollection<T>().First<T>(m => m.ID == id);
}
```

You might need to constrain T to a type that has the ID property if the compiler complains.

```
public T GetByID<T>(int id) where T : IHaveID
{
}
```